# How to get two tables within a textFrame at the same Height

Tags: migradoc

I have created two tables within a textFrame since I was told it is probably the best way to get two tables across from each other at the same height. When I fill in my data and headers for the table on the right, it does not extend to the bottom at the same height as the table to the left. Even when I add more AddParagraphs(), the bottom of the right table barley goes past the bottom border of the left table therefore making the tables not even in height. Is there a fix or different way of doing this? I want where it says "ADV Integrity" on the right table to extend at an even height with the left side of the table.

My code:

```
            //textFrame for Invoice info
            TextFrame billFrame = section.AddTextFrame();

            billFrame.Height = "5.0cm";
            billFrame.Width = "6.0cm";
            billFrame.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
            billFrame.Top = "7.5cm";
            billFrame.MarginRight = "10.0cm";
            billFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
            billFrame.Left = ShapePosition.Left;

            //putting table into the Invoice textFrame
            Table table = billFrame.AddTable();

            table.Borders.Width = 0.75;

            Column column = table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(7));
            column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

            //define headers of "Bill To" table
            Row row = table.AddRow();
            row.HeadingFormat = true;
            Cell cell = row.Cells[0];
            row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
            cell.AddParagraph("Bill To:");
            cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

            //showing data inside Bill table
            row = table.AddRow();
            cell = row.Cells[0];
            cell.AddParagraph("ADV Integrity");
            cell.AddParagraph("Attn: Wendy Courtright");
            cell.AddParagraph("P.O. Box 1449");
            cell.AddParagraph("Waller, TX 77484");
            cell.AddParagraph("United States");


            //textFrame for Invoice info
            TextFrame invoiceFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
            invoiceFrame.Height = "5.0cm";
            invoiceFrame.Width = "6.0cm";
            invoiceFrame.Left = ShapePosition.Right;

            //adding table inside Invoice textFrame
            table = invoiceFrame.AddTable();
            table.Borders.Width = 0.75;

            column = table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3.5));
            column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

            column = table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3.5));
            column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;


            //headers for Invoice table
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.HeadingFormat = true;
            cell = row.Cells[0];
            row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
            cell.AddParagraph("Date");
            cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

            cell = row.Cells[1];
            cell.AddParagraph("Invoice");
            cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

            //defining rows and data inside Invoice table
            row = table.AddRow();

            cell = row.Cells[0];
            cell.AddParagraph("04/30/2020");

            cell = row.Cells[1];
            cell.AddParagraph("2000498");

            row = table.AddRow();

            cell = row.Cells[0];
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
            row.Cells[0].Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 1;
            cell.AddParagraph("Account");

            row = table.AddRow();
            cell = row.Cells[0];
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 1;
            cell.AddParagraph("ADV Integrity");
```

What is currently looks like: 
[image: Invoice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a single table with an invisible column in the middle. Single table, one height, issue solved. You can use `MergeDown` if you want a single cell for the address.

With two tables, you can set the heights of the rows to make sure both tables have the same height. This could lead to new issues if the contents of a cell suddenly do not fit into the height of the table.